Check how many of my tweets are liked by a particular user. Twitter API
I want to know how many (my) tweets are liked by a particular user. I just want to know the count. I could do this in two steps:

First fetch all my tweets id https://api.twitter.com/2/users/${userid}/tweets
Then for each tweet get the liking user's id https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/${tweet_id}/liking_users?
Combine these liking user's id and count how many times the target_user_id exists.

I've basic plan.
Is there any other API or any better way to achieve the same?
